# django ajax audio file upload to views.py

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm a newbie in Django.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't send an audio file to *views.py* for further processing. Kindly help me in this thanks.

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" capture id="recorder">
<audio id="player" controls></audio>
<button id='button'>upload </button>

<script>
    var recorder = document.getElementById('recorder');
    var player = document.getElementById('player');

    recorder.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
         var file = e.target.files[0];
         player.src =  URL.createObjectURL(file);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: can you add your views.py code that handles this request too

Comment: i have not written any code for that in views.py.i dont know what to write for that

Comment: what should i write in this java script first, i dont know how to use ajax or XMLHttpRequest in this part..

Comment: please! any one help me ,m stuck

Comment: Sorry.. Can you take a look at this. Your issue is not particularly a problem, this is a whole learning step https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html

Comment: thanks sir , this link helps alot